# Kmeans clustering and mean vector

Tags: python, arrays, k-means, mean

I'm going to cluster the data into two clusters then calculate the mean vector for both clusters but I cant do it, the reason is that  mean does not work with arrays that do not have regular shape, any idea that how can I manage my data?

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1,1],[1.5,2],[3,4],[5,7],[3.5,5],[3,7],[3.5,4.5],[5,8],[5,1]])
centroid = np.array([[2.5,2.2],[4,6.3]])
clusters={}
for x in X:

  z= min([(i[0], np.linalg.norm(x-centroid[i[0]]))  for i in enumerate(centroid)], key=lambda t:t[1])

  try:
      clusters[z].append(x)
  except KeyError:
      clusters[z]=[x]

newmu = []
r=[]
d=[]
keys = sorted(clusters.keys())
for k in keys:
  if k[0]==0:
   r.append(clusters[(k[0],k[1])])

  else:
   d.append(clusters[(k[0],k[1])])

c=np.mean(d ,axis = 0)
f=np.mean(r,axis=0)
print c
print f
```

The variable r is : [[array([ 2.,  3.])], [array([ 1.5,  2. ])], [array([ 3.,  4.])], [array([ 1.
,  1.])], [array([ 5.,  1.])]] and there is no problem with that because it does have regular shape

The problem is in variable d: [[array([ 5.,  7.]), array([ 3.,  7.])], [array([ 3.5,  5. ])], [array([ 3.5,4.5])], [array([ 5.,  8.])]] it doesn't have regular shape so the mean doesn't work

Comment: What exactly do you want to have after calculating the mean of d? For exmaple: `d = [[a,b],[c,d]]` => `mean([a,b,c,d])` or `[mean([a,c]), mean([c,d])]`?

Comment: mean ( [array([ 5., 7.]), array([ 3., 7.])], [array([ 3.5, 5. ])], [array([ 3.5,4.5])], [array([ 5., 8.])]]]) = [5+3+3.5+3.5+5\5 ,7+7+5+4.5+8\5] the result should be =[4,6.3]

Answer (score 0):

You have to unpack d before calculating the mean:

```
... 
d = [item for sublist in d for item in sublist]
c = np.mean(np.array(d), axis=0)
...
```

Comment: Thanks-it worked but we exactly don't  know when we need to unpack because sometimes there is no same distance for two points. For example, if we change [3,7] to [3,1] the d would be like this: ( ([[array([ 5., 7.])], [array([ 3., 1.])], [array([ 3.5, 5. ])], [array([ 3.5,4.5])], [array([ 5., 8.])]]) and the unpack will result  [5,7,3,1,3.5,5,3.5,4.5,5,8] and the mean would be different.

Comment: No, the unpack won't result in what you have written. There is always a list containing a list of arrays.